# If statement in select using with join in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables which are `news (id, title, descrption)`, `cat (id, title)`, `newscat (id, newsID, catID)`. As you see each `news` can relate to any or some `cats`. I want one query to fetch all `cat`s and if `cat` is related to `news` 'checked'. I wrote this query:

```
SELECT
  c.id, c.title, IF (nc.newsID = $newsID, 'checked', null) as checked
FROM
  cat c
  LEFT JOIN newscat nc ON c.id = nc.catID
```

but this doesn't work. Some `cat`s come duplicate. What is the problem?

Comment: Maybe GROUP BY some column will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Using suggestion from Wr1t3r:

```
SELECT
  c.id, c.title, IF (COUNT(IF(nc.newsID=$NewsID,1,NULL)) > 0, 'checked', null) as checked
FROM
  cat c
  LEFT JOIN newscat nc ON c.id = nc.catID
  GROUP BY  c.id
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But i want query each time for particular news.